# Javascript - Can't get the value of the function outside of it, getting undefined

Tags: javascript

I am willing to get the value of the function outside of it; however, I am getting `undefined` here is the below code:

```js
getCoords() {
  let call = this.http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address + '&key=' + this.key).subscribe(data => {

    let lat = data.json().results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    let long = data.json().results[0].geometry.location.lng;

    this.latLong = {
      "lat": lat,
      "long": long
    };

    //I can get it here
    console.log('called >> ', this.latLong)

    return this.latLong;

  });

  //this.latlong is undefined !
}

//if I call getCoords() here I get undefined too
```

Comment: No value is returned from `getCoords` function. What does `.subscribe()` return?

Comment: Are you sure that `data` variable which you get after calling the URL is not `undefined` too?

Comment: The `subscribe` method is clearly **asynchronous**, hence the callback

Comment: @errata yes, after the ` });`

Answer (score 2):

If subscribe returns a `Promise`, `return` `call`, chain `.then()` to get the value `this.latLong` returned from within `.subscribe()`

```
getCoords() {
  let url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' 
             + address + '&key=' + this.key;
  let call = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => {

      let lat = data.json().results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      let long = data.json().results[0].geometry.location.lng;

      this.latLong = {
        "lat": lat,
        "long": long
      };

      //I can get it here
      console.log('called >> ', this.latLong)

      resolve(this.latLong);

    });
  });

  return call.then(res => { console.log(res); return res })
  //this.latlong is undefined !
}

getCoords()
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Tried that; however, it throws an error saying that '.then' does not exist on type Subscription

Comment: What does `.subscribe()` return?

Comment: `.subscribe()` is an observable that takes tree parameters `.subscribe(success, failure, complete)`

Comment: You can use `Promise` constructor to call `resolve()` within `success` or `reject` within `failure`, return the `Promise` constructor from call. See updated post

Comment: this one `return call.then(res => { console.log(res); return res })` replaced `undefined` by `__zone_symbol__state` which I don't know from where it came. For the last line `getCoords().then()` says that `property` then does not exists on type `void`

Comment: You need to include more details at Question. What is `__zone_symbol__state` ? Can you reproduce issue at plnkr https://plnkr.co? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I, myself don't know it, I believe it came from `Promise` constructor

Answer (score 0):

Sure, because `http.get` is async method so the callback function (`subscribe`) will call **after** the line `this.latlong` will call, so in that time `this.latlong` is `undefined`.

Comment: pretty logical, but how can I retrieve that value?

Comment: You have to do this **inside** the `subscribe` callback

Comment: Can you please be clear, an example will be very helpful

Comment: Just like the answer above, if you don't understand, let me know..